# Laravel 5.2 injecting object into Blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I am binding an employee model into a `Blade` template, and want to place the result of an eager load relation into a field.

In my controller I build the collection for the page as:

```
$employee = User::with('country', 'activeOrganisationRole')->first();
```

My form open statement is:

```
{!! Form::model($employee, ['route' => ['employee.role', $employee->uuid], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

So I want to populate `$employee->country->name` into an input `Laravel Collective form::text` statement, but I cannot get the country name to load. All other fields on the form load perfectly from the parent collection.

My Country field is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone" class="control-label">Country</label>
    {!! Form::text('country', null, ['id'=>'country', 'placeholder' => 'Country', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

The above country field loads the entire relation result into the input. What is the correct syntax for `injecting $employee->country->name` into this input?

By the way , this works perfectly, but I have learned nothing by doing this way!

```
<label for="title" class="control-label">Country</label>
<input id="country" class="form-control" value="{!! $employee->country->country !!}" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `FormBuilder` in LaravelCollective uses [`data_get`](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/helpers.php#L389) (a Laravel helper function) to get attributes from objects. However, dots in names of elements is kind of strange so I delved a little into the source for you.

You have one of the following choices (ordered by my preference):

1. You can add a method called `getFormValue` in your Employee model. This takes a single parameter which is the name of the form element that is requesting a value. Implement it something like this:

   ```
   public function getFormValue($name)
   {
       if(empty($name)) {
           return null;
       }

       switch ($name) {
           case 'country':
               return $this->country->country;
       }

       // May want some other logic here:
       return $this->getAttribute($name);
   }
   ```

   I couldn't really find any documentation on this (such is sometimes the way with Laravel). I only found it by [trawling the source](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.2/src/FormBuilder.php#L1105) - although it really is easy with PhpStorm<sup><sub><sup>Shamless Plug</sup></sub></sup>

   The downside with this is that you lose the transformation and attempt at extracting values from your employee object with `data_get`.
2. Change the name of your text field to be `country[country]`. In the source the builder replaces '[' and ']' with '.' and '' respectively when looking in an object for an attribute. This means `data_get` will be looking for `country.country`.
3. *I put this here for people with the issue in the future, but it's not recommended*.

   Give your employee model a `getCountryAttribute` method. As explained under the "Form Model Accessors" heading in [the documentation](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding), you can overwrite what gets returned from $employee->country. This means you can't access the real object though.